# SQL Query using max

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Trying to create an automatic playoff of ladder for NFL league site.

i have made rather a few attempts at getting it, but it seems to be eluding me.

```
SELECT team, Max(win) as win, loss FROM db WHERE conf="nfc" GROUP BY division
```

What i need it to do is select the team with the highest number of wins from each division and return the team name and record.

The secondary part to this, would then be selecting all the teams that are NOT in above list, and displaying the top two wins

Comment: Why can't you do this with a simple SELECT, COUNT and GROUP BY with an ORDER BY? Why MAX() at all? And why, when you used the SQL tag and got the big box suggesting you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using did you ignore that suggestion?

Comment: Query above should return what you want. Only not if server do not know what division is? Maybe print screen your tables?

Comment: Remember, with a `group by` clause, all fields mentioned in the select are now aggregated, and if there are multiple values possible in a field, it must be grouped.  I.E., any field in select that will have different values within the grouping must be listed in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The issue the mysql does not know which team in grouped records to return. But it does know which wins to return as max map multiple recorded to one value.

Use sub query

```
SELECT t1.team, t1.win, t1.loss FROM table t1 WHERE win = (SELECT max(win) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.division = t1.division);
```